# Non rendered field bound to managed bean not firing setter

Tags: xpages, managed-bean

I suspect this is a silly question, but here goes...

I have two fields on a custom control, both are bound to managed bean properties (as opposed to document fields). The second field is only rendered when a specific value is chosen in the first field.

What I am seeing is that the setter for the second field is not firing after it has been rendered (the getter is firing just fine).

I have worked around the problem by computing the CSS display property on the second field to be block or none depending on the value in the first field. Everything works fine in this situation, it seems to be specifically related to whether the second field is rendered when the page is first loaded.

*****Edit
Here's the sample code block:

```
    <div class="control-group">
    <xp:label value="Party Type:" id="partytypelabel" for="party_typetv">
    </xp:label>
    <div class="controls">
        <xp:comboBox id="party_typetv" value="#{InvolvedRecord.partytypetv}"
            required="true" defaultValue=""
            readonly="#{javascript:!InvolvedManager.isInEditMode()}">
            <xp:selectItem itemLabel="&lt;select&gt;" itemValue="">
            </xp:selectItem>
            <xp:selectItems>
                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:InvolvedManager.getPartyTypes()}]]></xp:this.value>
            </xp:selectItems>
            <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true"
                refreshMode="partial" disableValidators="true" refreshId="partyfields">
            </xp:eventHandler>
        </xp:comboBox>
    </div>
</div>
<xp:panel id="partyfields" tagName="fieldset">
    <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:InvolvedManager.hasPartyType()}]]></xp:this.rendered>
    <xp:div styleClass="control-group">
        <xp:label for="Adverse_Party_TypeTL" value="Type:" id="adversepartytypelabel">
        </xp:label>
        <div class="controls">
            <span>
                <xp:comboBox id="Adverse_Party_TypeTL"
                    value="#{InvolvedRecord.adversepartytypetl}" readonly="#{javascript:!InvolvedManager.isInEditMode()}">
                    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="&lt;select&gt;"
                        itemValue="">
                    </xp:selectItem>
                    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Company" itemValue="Company">
                    </xp:selectItem>
                    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Individual" itemValue="Individual">
                    </xp:selectItem>
                    <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true"
                        refreshMode="partial" disableValidators="true" refreshId="adversepartyfields">
                    </xp:eventHandler>
                </xp:comboBox>
            </span>
        </div>
    </xp:div>
</xp:panel>
```

*****End Edit

This is running on an 8.5.3 server.

Has anyone seen anything like this or maybe offer an explanation as I am confused!

Comment: Do you reload the whole page when the second field should appear and get a value or do you do a partial refresh of the second one?

Comment: I've tried both and it doesn't make any difference. In either case the setter is not even being called, let alone persisting the value of the property across the ajax request.

Comment: Can you post the source of this XSP block?

Comment: I've edited the original post to include the XSP markup

Comment: To clarify, this blocks the setter on all subsequent events?

Comment: Yes that's correct. Seems like this applies equally to fields managed by beans and those managed by the document binding as well.

Comment: Check the network traffic to see what data is being sent; I'm curious whether this is impacting client-side behavior, server-side, or both.

Comment: No the data from the fields is definitely be posted back to the server and then lost as the setter is not being called.

Interestingly, Mark Myers just found this article which indicates this may be standard JSF functionality: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/myfaces-users/200808.mbox/%3C48986E2B.6020704@chello.at%3E

Comment: I suspected a standard JSF mechanism as well...FWIW I actually get around this particular issue by doing what the guy in the post didn't want to do which is to manage the data in the session-scoped bean as well.  So...a save records the data within the bean as well as in the document.  This architecture is required though for our application and may not readily apply to other apps.

Comment: I suspect this is what I'll end up doing, but do you have this situation where fields are progressively disclosed? How do you get their values before the save?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could render the component in all phases except the renderphase. This would allow to set the value during update phase, but would hide it to the client.

Here is an example:
[Conditionally hidden edit box in a partially refreshed panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14874923/conditionally-hidden-edit-box-in-a-partially-refreshed-panel/14877315#14877315)

**EDIT:**

```
<xp:this.rendered>
   <![CDATA[#{javascript:
      if( view.isRenderingPhase() ){
         return InvolvedManager.hasPartyType();
      }else{
         return true;
      }
   }]]>
</xp:this.rendered>
```

Comment: That's perfect, thanks Sven. No idea why I didn't know about this already!

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually entering data into these fields after they have been rendered?  I have found on many occasions that a field specifically bound to a managed bean does not actually even do anything unless some data has been entered into it.  For instance, I have seen this: render the field dynamically, don't do anything to it, save the data source, no field whatsoever on the document.  If I do that same activity but add data to the field, then it all works.  Not an answer.  Just some info.

Comment: Thanks Russ, yes in this case I am selecting a value from a combo box and the data is definitely being posted back to the server, just being lost at that point. As mentioned above I think we've found that this is standard JSF functionality: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/myfaces-users/200808.mbox/%3C48986E2B.6020704@chello.at%3E